# Diagonalisable mappings

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Let $V$ be the vector space of real polynomials in $x$ of degree at most $d$ where d>0. Are the following linear mappings of $V$ into itself diagonalisable?

$$(i) \qquad T_1: f(x)\longmapsto x\frac{df}{dx}$$ 
and
$$(ii)\qquad T_2:f(x)\longmapsto \frac{df}{dx}.$$

I think about the eigenvalue but how to get the eigenvalue from the information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Observe that $T_1(x^k)=kx^k$, for all $k=0,\ldots,d$. Hence, $\{1,x,\ldots,x^d\}$ is basis of $V$ consisting of eigenvectors of $T_1$. Hence $T_1$ is diagonalisable.
2. Clearly $T_2^{d+1}f=f^{(d+1)}=0$, for all $f$, but $T_2^d (x^d)= d!\ne 0$. This means that the minimal polynomial of $T_2$ is $m(x)=x^{d+1}$ and hence $T_2$ is not diagonalisable - Here we use the fact that the minimal polynomial of diagonalisable matrix has simple roots.

Comment: for one why this is the basis of eigenvectors?

Comment: @stedmoaoa What is th definition of an eigenvector? $Tu=\lambda u$. Here, $u=x^k$, $\lambda=k$.

Comment: Yes I got it. And for 2 can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @stedmoaoa As $T_2$ is nilpotent, then it has only one eigenvalue $\lambda=0$. This means that its characteristic polynomial is $(-x)^{d+1}$. It $T_2$ was diagonalisable, then its minimal polynomial would have to be $m(x)=x$, i.e., $T_2$ would have to vanish!

Comment: I understand but can you explain not with nilpotent since I haven't learned that yet.

Comment: @stedmoaoa I have modified my answer.

Comment: Thank you. My problem was I don't know about the fact about the minimal polynomial

Comment: Can you please explain for the first one why when it is the basis for the eigenvectors then it is diagonalizable?

Comment: If you have a linear mapping $T:V\to V$, then a basis $u_1,\ldots,u_n$ of the space defines a matrix $A=(a_{ij})$, i.e. $Tu_i=a_{i1}u_1+\cdots+a_{in}u_n$. If the basis consists of eigenvectors, then $A$ is diagonal.